# Merge bottom border

Tags: css

Has anybody got any idea of how to merge the borders of the 3 elements so that they join together.This is what I currently have:[image: This is where I am currently]

```
<div style="float: left; padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
    <table id="table": cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr align="center" valign="middle" >
            <td style="padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
               <div id="schedulePrevDay" title="Previous Day" class="borderRad_3Left">&nbsp;</div>

               <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="compactDate" MaxLength="10" Width="65px"></asp:TextBox>

               <div id="scheduleNextDay" title="Next Day" class="borderRad_3Right">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: negative margin will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're using border-right and border-left 1px solid #fff. So, just remove the border from there:

```
#schedulePrevDay{
   border-right: none;
}
#scheduleNextDay{
   border-left: none;
}
```

Or, you may use negative margin on them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a negative margin as Bhojendra Nepal suggested, so it will look something like this

```
<div style="float: left; padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
<table id="table": cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr align="center" valign="middle" >
        <td style="padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
           <div id="schedulePrevDay" title="Previous Day" class="borderRad_3Left" style="margin-right:-1px;">&nbsp;</div>

           <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="compactDate" MaxLength="10" Width="65px"></asp:TextBox>

           <div id="scheduleNextDay" title="Next Day" class="borderRad_3Right" style="margin-left:-1px;">&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ive used styles but you should also check if there is no padding, margin or borders on these elements before doing a negative margin.